# Connecting c++ program to database - kind of unique way

Tags: c++, sql, database, postgresql

Ok, so I have this database made by postgreSQL and I'm wondering if and how can I connect my database and my c++ program. I want to like send .exe file to my friend and then everytime he opens it, it would like send some of his information to my database under PK (primary key) id and then all the info my program "stole", like IP and some stuff.

All the stuff is for educational purposes only! I have postgreSQL skills and C++ skills, but I never figured out, how I could actualy do this. I have searched on internet for hours, with no reasonable help, I would like example of something like that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about spyware application writing.

Comment: believe it or not, I was just wondering on how this is done, as you may have heard in many movies they do this and many people in programing world talk about it. It is a huge disadvantage to not know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connecting to a database from a remote unknown client will be a security risk since you'd have to open the db server to accept connections from all ips.

A safer way to do it would be creating a web service that connects locally (in the server) to your db and have your desktop application consume that service sending the data as params. There are a few libraries to do rest services in this question: [How can I implement a RESTful webservice using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298113/how-can-i-implement-a-restful-webservice-using-c)

Comment: This would be a much safer way to connect to a database, but application developers should never collect information from a user's computer without first letting the user know about the information the application wants to send.

Comment: Are you saying that I make a web aplication that will do that?

Comment: Well, that's one way to do it. It doesn't have to be a full fledged web app, just a web service that you connect to from your desktop application. You could also do it using a TCP or a UDP connection between a service (that resides in the server where the db is located) and the desktop app, which I guess is simpler and better if you don't know much about web development.